# Opposite regex for years notepad

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello I need Opposite for this regex to use wih notepad+++

```
\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2,4}[+-]
```

Now It's replace years

```
ML 12+ (W166) = ML (W166)
FREELANDER II 07+ = FREELANDER II
Kuga 08-12 = Kuga
CRV 2012+ = CRV
RX270/350 10+ = RX270/350
QASHQAI 2+ = QASHQAI 2+
TRIBECA 05 = TRIBECA 
XC60 = XC60
```

on right side (after '=') I show how it's works. I need Opposite effect like this

```
ML 12+ (W166) = 12
FREELANDER II 07+ = 07
Kuga 08-12 = 08-12
CRV 2012+ = 2012
RX270/350 10+ = 10
QASHQAI 2+ = 
TRIBECA 05 = 05 
XC60 =
```

Comment: shouldn't the last test case (`XC60`) be replaced by `60`?

Comment: No I need leave it like XC60 because I have 20 mb file, with many others makes like XC80 XC90 or V60 e.t.c

Comment: @user2687340 You should start [marking answers to your questions as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to show that your question has been solved and as a way to show which answers have been most useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

Find:

```
^.*?(?<digits>\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2,4}).*?$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Here's an online test: http://regex101.com/r/nY6uE5

It replaces all rows OK, except the one that doesn't match (`QASHQAI 2+`)

After applying this replace, you can get rid of the non-match rows, by replacing `^.*[^\d-].*$` with an empty string.

---

Update: OK now I understood the requirement that the digit pattern must be preceded by a space. The regex should be:

```
^.*?\s(?<digits>(\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{2,4})).*?$
```

(http://regex101.com/r/dN2sH9)

Comment: Works good except values like this LX570 07- and IX55 07+ and RX400h 05-09

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
\s(\d+[\-]?)[^+](\d+)?
```

You can extract $1 and $2 to get your answer.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My solution but need still a fix.
Find what: `(.+)(\s\d+)(.+=).+`
Replace with: `$1$2$3 $2`

Result almost done but need a fix.

```
ML 12+ (W166) = 12
FREELANDER II 07+ = 07
Kuga 08-12 = 08
CRV 2012+ = 2012
RX270/350 10+ = 10
QASHQAI 2+ = 2
TRIBECA 05 = 05
XC60 = XC60
```